# Python recursive function result depends on previous calls when parameter has default value

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

I made this function:

```
def test(num,v=[]):
    v.append(num)
    if num == 10:
        return v
    return test(num+1,v)
```

When I use it, the result of previous calls seems to still be there:

```
>>> test(3)
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> test(3)
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> test(3)
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

If I use just `v` in the function declaration as opposed to `v=[]`, it seems to work.
What am I missing? I want the function to be fresh each time I run it. I use Python 2.7.3.

Comment: Will you ever pass anything as the second argument of this function (`test(3, other_list)`)?

Comment: No, @Blender, I use a default argument to initiate a value for my recursive function succinctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an object as a default argument the same instance of the object is used for all calls to that function. This works fine for immutable objects but becomes a problem for mutable objects. The same object is modified and reused multiple times when the function probably expects to have a "new" object.

You can use a workaround like this to get the functionality you want:

```
def test(num,v=None):
    if v is None:
        v = []
    ....
```

Comment: While your first sentence is true as written, to be clear, the same instances are also used for immutable objects like integers and strings.  IOW it's not a mutability issue per se.

Comment: Thanks. Wow, that's very unintuitive, I've been using python for ~2 years and have no idea it works this way.

Comment: @DSM: good point, but the mutability is what makes it an issue

Comment: @Tim: sure, but if you think of it as "mutable objects behave differently from immutable ones" it seems like an unintuitive quirk.  If you think of the arguments as part of the `def`, and not part of the function, it makes perfect sense why Python acts as it does.